# Javascript input text loses value after entering values in another input (using livewire)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using livewire in laravel project. I wanted create a repeater so user can add more rows with a button. But one of the fields is a search field. So if the user types 13 characters there and there is a product in the database with this barcode then the first 2 fields are populated. The problem is that there is a strange flashing when a match occurs. Sometimes it keeps the right value and sometimes fields are empty. When the fields have values, when I type in another field then the fields lose their values! Here is the table with the repeater fields:

```
<tbody>
            @foreach ($products as $index => $product)
                <tr class="repeater-item">
                    <td >
                        <input class="prod-id" type="text" name="products[{{ $index }}][product]" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.product_id">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="prod-name" type="text" name="products[{{ $index }}][product]" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.product">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="search" type="text" name="products[{{ $index }}][barcode]" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.barcode">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="prod-tainia" type="text" name="products[{{ $index }}][tainia]" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.tainia">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="prod-lot" type="text" name="products[{{ $index }}][lot]" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.lot">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="prod-expdate" type="text" name="products[{{ $index }}][expdate]" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.expdate">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="products[{{ $index }}][quantity]" wire:model="products.{{ $index }}.quantity">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" wire:click="removeProduct({{ $index }})">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').on('keyup', '.search', function(ev){  
                ev.preventDefault();
                var query = $(this).val(); 
                if(query.length == 13){ 
                    var parentRepeater = $(this).closest('.repeater-item');
                    if(query != '')
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"{{ route('products.search')  }}",
                            method:"GET",
                            data:{search:query},
                            dataType:'json',
                            success:function(data)
                            { 
                                if(data[0].name.length > 5){ 
                                    parentRepeater.find('.prod-id').val(data[0].id);
                                    parentRepeater.find('.prod-name').val(data[0].name); 
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you trigger an update to a `wire:model`, it triggers the update cycle of Livewire (learn more on the lifecycle [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks)). In this cycle, a request is made to the server (the Livewire component), where the property is updated. It then sends a request back, with the updated data. You're performing an unnecessary request by also *manually* calling an extra request on change. You're then creating a racing condition, depending on which request finishes first. Using manual (`$.ajax`, `window.XMLHttpRequest`) requests inside a Livewire component is really not adviced, as Livewire exists to make these requests for you in an easy (and safe!) manner.

Instead, I would suggest a `wire:change="searchProduct({{$index}})"` on the `.search` row, then have a `searchProduct` method inside your Livewire component. There, I would implement whatever you have on the route you're currently calling, and modify the data on the server side inside the Livewire component. This will fix your flashing, as well as reduce requests.